# How to create a streaming API for flutter to subscribe to?

Tags: flutter, api, express, stream

I'm trying to get message from an API I builed in express in **Flutter**.

The thing is, to get my messages I had the build a streambuilder beacause I want the list of message to update on new messages. To achieve this, a create a steam method that check the API every *x* seconds.

```dart
  Stream<List<Message>> streamMessage() async* {
    final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
    var json = (await storage.read(key: 'user'))!;
    User user = User.fromJson(jsonDecode(json));
    jwt = user.jwt;

    yield* Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 3), (_) async {
      http.Response response = await http.get(
          Uri.parse("https://myapi.com/messages"),
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $jwt',
          });

      List<Message> messages = [];
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var list = List.from(jsonDecode(response.body)).reversed;
        messages = list.map((e) => Message.fromJson(e)).toList();
      } else {
        log("Error : ${response.statusCode} -- ${response.reasonPhrase}");
      }
      return messages;
    }).asyncMap(
      (value) async => await value,
    );
  }
```

It work, but it have a lot of issues.

- the update is not as fast as I want
- it's a lot of request for nothing
- the API can easily get overloaded
- This way look more like a workaround than a real function

I would like to create a mechanisme in my backend to act more like a real stream subscibtion. As it work with Firebase. But I have no clues how it work, or even what to search.

If you have any hint, how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this with websockets which will require some config on your node app and your Flutter app.

I'd suggest using [Flutter socket.io client](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client) and [node socket.io server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io).

Note that the stable version of the flutter client is not up to date with the current version of the node server. You can either use the beta version 2 of the flutter client or an older version of the server.

Last time I set this up I chose the latter. `Version 1.01` of the client definitely works with node server `version 2.4.1`.

Here's a basic example with a stateful widget but if you want to use a `StreamBuilder` there's an example on the client pub.dev page. It can be tied into any state management solution.

```
class SocketExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const SocketExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SocketExampleState createState() => _SocketExampleState();
}

class _SocketExampleState extends State<SocketExample> {
  static const _sockerURL = 'your node app url';

  static const _socketEvent = 'event_1';

  final _socket = IO.io(sockerURL, <String, dynamic>{
    "transports": ["websocket"],
    "autoConnect": false,
  });

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _socket.connect();
    _socket.onConnect((data) {
      log('Connected ${_socket.connected}');
    });
    _socket.on(socketEvent, (message) {
      // whatever needs to happen when you get an event from the server
      // put it here
    });
  }

 @override
  void dispose() {
    _socket.disconnect();
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ...
  }
}
```

And a basic setup on the node side would look something like this

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);

const socketEvent = "event_1"; // this string needs to correspond to the event in your flutter app

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on(socketEvent, (msg) => {
    io.emit(socketEvent, msg);

    console.log("message: " + msg);
  });
});
```

Then on whichever GET/POST etc... you need in the node you send a message to Flutter with

```
 io.emit(socketEvent, whatever the payload to your Flutter app is goes here);
```

That's pretty much all you have to do get real time updates in Flutter from a node app without manually refreshing or checking the API at any interval.